# Fast synchronisation of films and subtitles in VLC 2.2.51

Tags: sync, vlc-media-player, dvd, subtitles

VLC 2.2.5.1 on macOS Sierra 10.12.5

I have reviewed various questions and answers on this topic, but I'm unable to make my subtitles work.

The situation is the following: I have a DVD of a Hungarian film with French subtitles. I want to put English or Italian subtitles on the film instead.

I can open the film, and I can download subtitle tracks and add them to the film on VLC. The downloaded subtitle tracks display, but at the wrong time.

Opening the .srt file, it appears that:

- there are subtitles in the .srt file which VLC does not display at the indicated time;
- the subtitle display times in the .srt file are not the same as for the DVD version of the film I have.

My attempted solution:

- first load the subtitles track;
- with the film paused, use the Track Synchronisation option on the drop-down Window menu to change the subtitle delay;

This doesn't work. Either the subtitles remain delayed, or the subtitle track doesn't show despite being loaded, even if I change the delay setting. I then have to reload the film from DVD to be able to add the subtitle track again.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Without an example, which is impossible in your case, all we can do is theorize. Maybe the subtitles file you have does not match the DVD?

Comment: I can add the .srt to the DVD, I want to adjust it so it *does* match the DVD playback; it's when I adjust that the displayed subtitles disappear or are not adjusted. I'm wondering why the adjustment features don't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You have issue that the subtitles you have were for different version of your DVD version.

Your attempt does not work because there are different delays between dialogs or there could even be some new/missing scenes - thus different time delays in the subtitles.

**To fix it** for good you **have to re-sync** it.

I can recommend [URUWork's Subtitle Workshop](http://www.uruworks.net/index.html) it is for free and if you find it helpful you can donate.

The other option is to use [KMplayer alas Crystal player](http://www.kmplayer.com/mac) which is currently BETA for Mac, but you can adjust your subtitles while watching and then save them.

Answer (score 0):

Out of sync subtitles can be automatically resynced using the tool [Subsync](https://subsync.online). Subsync listens to the audio, so it can handle more then just a simple shift.

It can be used online or downloaded and used offline.